# Clojure programming exercise for calculating change

Tags: clojure

I'm learning Clojure and have written a small function to calculate change. I don't like few things about the code and would primarily like to replace recursive call with something more idiomatic. Could you please comment on the code and suggest a better (more Clojure-like) way of implementing it?

```
(def in-bank #{1 2 5 10})

(defn smaller-than? [compare-input metric]
  (>= compare-input metric))

(defn get-max-smaller-than [input]
  (apply max (filter (partial smaller-than? input) in-bank)))

(defn change-calc [change-requested change-given]
  (let [calculated
    (get-max-smaller-than change-requested)]
    (let [upd-change-given
      (conj change-given calculated)]
        (let [sub-request (- change-requested calculated)]
          (if (= sub-request 0)
            upd-change-given (recur sub-request upd-change-given))))))
```

Answer (score 4):

First, there is nothing wrong with your recursive call: `recur` is about as idiomatic as Clojure gets.

Now, let's try to improve your code.

- If you look at it, `smaller-than?` is a synonym for `>=`. It just
  passes it the same arguments in the same order.

You could define it as ...

```
(def smaller-than? >=)
```

... or, better, just use `>=`. If you want your own name, you'd have been better to call it `not-smaller-than?`.

- There is no need to nest `let`s in `change-calc`. One `let` will do.
  Successive bindings    in a `let` are evaluated in order.
- Try to choose suggestive names. I'd replace the meaningless
  `calculated` with something like `candidate`.

Thus we get

```
(defn max-smaller-than [input]
  (apply max (filter (partial >= input) in-bank)))

(defn change-calc [change-requested change-given]
  (let [candidate (max-smaller-than change-requested)
        upd-change-given (conj change-given candidate)
        sub-request (- change-requested candidate)]
          (if (= sub-request 0)
            upd-change-given (recur sub-request upd-change-given))))
```

There are a couple of worries here:

- We'd better deal with a zero `change-requested` directly than work
  out it's going to be zero next time round.
- The test for `sub-request` is for *exactly* zero. What happens if we 
  can't give exact change? (With `1` in `in-bank`, this will not arise.
  But if it ever does, `max` throws an arity exception).

These revisions get us to

```
(defn change-calc [change-requested change-given]
  (if (pos? change-requested)
    (let [candidate (max-smaller-than change-requested)
          upd-change-given (conj change-given candidate)
          sub-request (- change-requested candidate)]
      (recur sub-request upd-change-given))
    change-given))
```

But this doesn't deal with the exception throwing problem. What is perhaps a better solution to this follows.

---

Let's look at the problem afresh.

Your code returns

- its second (sequence) argument with ...
- the change from the `in-bank` denominations conj-ed onto it, so at
  the front/back if the sequence is a list/vector.

In any programming language, the second function should be distinct: especially in Clojure, where it is easy to append to a vector.

How do we do it?

- For the change, we can return a count of how many coins there are of
  each denomination, using a map from denomination to number. If
  Clojure had a standard multiset/bag, we'd use it instead.
- And let's make the denomination set an explicit argument.

If we want to make up a `sum` from a number of `denom`ination`s`, we can do the following:

```
(defn change [sum denoms]
  (reduce
    (fn [[ans ch :as both] d]
      (let [c (quot ch d)]
        (if (zero? c) both [(assoc ans d c) (mod ch d)])))
     [{} sum]
     (sort > denoms)))
```

This is more or less the algorithm you wrote, with a few wrinkles:

- We sort the denominations in decreasing order.
- We deal with each once and for all through a `reduce`.
- We use `quot` and `mod` to short-circuit a loop using subtraction.

The result is a pair:

- a map representing a multiset of how many (non-zero) there are of
  each denomination, and
- a number for how much change is left over unreconciled.

Examples:

```
(change 8 in-bank)
;[{1 1, 2 1, 5 1} 0]

(change 8 #{2 5 10})
;[{2 1, 5 1} 1]

(change 13 #{1 5 10})
;[{1 3, 10 1} 0]
```

- The idea of returning the residue too arose from the algorithm, where 
  it is part of the working.
- If `1` is a denomination, the residue is always `0`.
- A development might be to know how many of each coin were present to
  start with.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to note is that you dont have to use 3 different let statements, you could just use one instead (each new 2-tuple in the let binding group is aware to all its previous bindings).

Another thing, you might not want to expose 'change-given' to the user, since it generally has to be an empty list, so you could "confine" your recursion using the loop macro, like this:

```
(defn change-calc [change-requested]
  (loop [change-requested change-requested change-given []]
    (let [calculated       (get-max-smaller-than change-requested)
          upd-change-given (conj change-given calculated)
          sub-request      (- change-requested calculated)]
      (if (zero? sub-request)
        upd-change-given
        (recur sub-request upd-change-given)))))
```

If you really wanted to get rid of explicit recursion, you could always use implicit one, using methods such as reduce and iterate. here is an example:

```
(defn change-calc [change-requested]
  (second
   (last
    (take-while (complement nil?)
                (iterate (fn[[n coins]]
                           (when (pos? n)
                             (let [coin (get-max-smaller-than n)]
                               [(- n coin) (cons coin coins)]))) [change-requested []])))))
```

reduce is a catamorphism, which informally shrinks a list into a number. You are looking for the reverse operation, blowing a number into a list, this is called anamorphism. You could read [this interesting blog post](http://www.matlux.net/blog/2014/05/04/anamorphic-adventure-in-clojure) about anamorphisms in clojure

Comment: This applies a set of numbers (the implicit denominations argument) to a number and produces a multiset/bag of numbers, albeit not recognised as such in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified version using loop-recur.
Use vector for in-bank to find biggest denom faster.
You are using `set` and `filter+max` which do a lot more work than `filter+first`.

```
(def in-bank [10 5 2 1])

(defn change-calc [n]
  (loop [rem n change []]
    (if-let [sm (first (filter (partial >= rem) in-bank))]
      (recur (- rem sm) (conj change sm))
      change)))
```

---

To answer how is this better, using criterium bench original code clocks in 15ms, my code - 7.5ms for `(change-calc 99999)`
Using vector for in-bank fit better here.

Comment: why is it better than the original post?

Comment: @Malachi it's shorter and easier to read.

Comment: also note that in-bank is a vector and don't need to filter and apply max and find first instead.

Comment: so your review of the original post is "use a vector it's faster" ?  this isn't a good review, you should explain how it makes the code faster and better.

Comment: @Malachi yes, it's the answer to "suggest a better (more Clojure-like) way of implementing it". It is more concise, faster and more Clojure-like.